# How to save slicer profiles?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, prusaslicer

I've taken a bit of vacation and forgotten all the settings that I uncovered while tinkering with my printers.  Different settings for different printers for different materials.  I use Cura and PrusaSlicer, and they both behave more or less (randomly) the same.  Sometimes they save some things, most of the time they don't save the important stuff.  Neither slicer ever saves profiles, nor does it seem to have an option to, and they go weird if you change anything.

How are you supposed to save profiles?  Can I save them out to a file for later import when I need them?

I realize that both will probably have different ways to circumnavigate profiles, so I don't mind breaking it out into 2 questions if need be.

Me?  Oh I've just been hating profile saving for 12+0 years back when it was Slic3r.  At least with that software I could save them as a file and make sure that they were imported at the start of every single print.

An example of randomness: on this print on a large diameter printer, the infill speed was set to 4mm/s in Cura, making the print time 9 hours.  Once I fixed that, the print time was less than 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Both Cura and PrusaSlicer save settings as comments in G-code files, so you should be able to recover settings form Gcode files, and save them as new profiles. I generally save projects along with G-code files, for extra security.